# getting /dev/disk0 error when using dd command on iPhone mobile terminal

Tags: iphone, terminal, dd, invalid-argument

I am using the command `dd if=/dev/disk0 | ssh username@labtop ip address 'dd of=iphone-dump.img'` but am getting this: `dd: reading '/dev/disk0': Invalid argument`.

I am using iPhone 4 with iOs 5.1 and am trying to get some family photos back that I never backed up but restored my phone.  I haven't used my iPhone much since the restore so I'm sure the data is still on my phone somewhere.  I use MobileTerminal on my iPhone.

Is there a new `dd` command I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

If you really "restored" (and not "updated") your iPhone, there is no way to back up any data.